# Changing an image when clicking a thumbnail, with multiple instances on one page

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am trying to create a page which has several instances of large images with smaller thumbnails.

I want to make it so that when the user clicks on a thumbnail the large image in the parent div of the thumbnail to the large version of the thumbnail.

I know how to make this happen if there is only one instance of this on the page, but I'm having trouble with multiple instances.

Here is the code I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div>
<img src="upload/1374000286_large.jpg" />
    <div class="thumbnails" >
        <img src="upload/1374000286_small.jpg" />
        <img src="upload/1374000773_small.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.thumbnails').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('small','large'));
    })
});
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra `})` in your jQ.

Comment: Here element with class 'thumbnails' is a DIV. You html code doesn't make much sense for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will bind a function on the `onclick` event of each image whose `src` attribute contains the string **small** and proceed to the change of the **large image's** source, **sibling of the the parent div**, when the thumbnail is clicked:

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$.each($('img'), function () {
    if ($(this).attr('src').toString().indexOf('small.jpg') > -1) {
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            console.log("test");
            $(this).parent('div').siblings('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('small', 'large'));
        });
    }
});
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yqkcY/)

Comment: Makes perfect sense !